# Firebase 9.0.2 authentication error codes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

According to old docs firebase provide authentication error as firebase error which provides code in it but in new firebase 9.0.2 it will only exception which can be cast to FirebaseAuthException and has getCode but string. Now i want to get all the possible errors in firebase. I have tried but could not find any solution. Ios has handle error section and provides error with code(int) and not in Android. Please help. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3):

For getting all the possible errors in FirebaseAuth you can do something like this:

```
private void handleAuthenticationException(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
        if (((FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) exception).getErrorCode().equals("ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL")) {
            //do something...
        }
    }
    // Other relevant exceptions for you...
}
```

And call this method from your OnFailureListener like this:

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).
    .addOnSuccessListener(/*Your code here!*/)
    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            handleAuthenticationException(exception);
        }
    );
```

Please check the [FirebaseAuthException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/package-summary#exceptions) documentation for more information.

Comment: yeah i did like this too but its not kind of flexible to use. Older version and ios have FirAuthError which returns code i integer. So i was hoping for solution like that. Anyway thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to Toast the Error by following code at any place that might went wrong.

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Explain how this works and why it answers the question.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this solution :)